# Is it possible in R to make auto.arima choose the best model according to other criteria than aicc, aic or bic?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, arima

I would like to run auto.arima function in R on monthly data and its 3 criteria of selecting the best model are aicc, aic and bic. I'd like to use an out of sample measure like MAPE. Is it possible to create a workaround or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, it has to be one of the three. Although you may be able to do it yourself, if you are willing to change the code. If you have a look at myarima code inside auto.arima, you will find the following segment

```
if (method == "CSS") {
      fit$aic <- offset + nstar * log(fit$sigma2) + 2 * npar
    }
    if (!is.na(fit$aic)) {
      fit$bic <- fit$aic + npar * (log(nstar) - 2)
      fit$aicc <- fit$aic + 2 * npar * (npar + 1) / (nstar - npar - 1)
      fit$ic <- switch(ic, bic = fit$bic, aic = fit$aic, aicc = fit$aicc)
    }
    else {
      fit$aic <- fit$bic <- fit$aicc <- fit$ic <- Inf
    }
```

You could try changing the fit$aic values to a custom measure.